# UICollectionViewCell setAsset unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a photo gallery.  My `cellForItemAtIndexPath` code is below.

```
  - (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];   
    ALAsset *asset = self.assets[indexPath.row];
    cell.asset = asset; // crash on this line
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
    return cell;
}
```

The App crashes at line `cell.asset = asset;` giving error: `-[UICollectionViewCell setAsset:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa226fd0`.

The PhotoCell.h is ilke this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface PhotoCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property(nonatomic, strong) ALAsset *asset;

@end
```

And PhotoCell.m is :

```
#import "PhotoCell.h"

@interface PhotoCell ()
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *photoImageView;
@end

@implementation PhotoCell
- (void)setAsset:(ALAsset *)asset
{
    _asset = asset;
    self.photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]];
}

@end
```

I couldn't get any reason why the app is crashing.  Where am I making mistake?  Anything to do with the Storyboard contents?

Comment: Have you registered your custom cell nib by calling `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` on `UICollectionView` instance?

Comment: Thanks Amar.  It worked for me.  Pl see my comment to Bilal as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register your cell Class with your UICollectionView

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[PhotoCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell"];
```

Comment: Thanks Bilal.  Yes, this solved my crash issue when I added this in my viewDidload.  However, I was getting blank cells on the screen, no images.  On further exploration, i found that the storyboard was not linked to the correct variable.  However, the crash was solved with your solution.  Thank you.